# Remove test bots from Firebase Bigquery export

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I try to export Google Firebase analytics data in Google Big Query. From there i want to create custom reports in Google Data Studio. The integration works and i see all the events in BigQuery. 
Nevertheless i have a mismatch in the data, especially in the first_open event. There are more first_open events in BigQuery than i see in the build-in Firebase analytics tools. They are created everytime i upload the app to the Google Play Store.

I already filter out everything that runs in the 'firebase.test.lab' context, which works and filters the Google Play Pre-Launch report devices.

The devices i want to filter out are always Nexus 5X running on Android 6.0.1 and create around 40 first_open events per upload. The only difference i can observe is a change i the language field.

Is there any setting where i can disable these bots, or remove these from getting exported to BigQuery or reliably filter them?

A typical event that i want to filter out looks like this

```
{ 
   "event_date":"20191111",
   "event_timestamp":"1573496771938000",
   "event_name":"first_open",
   "event_params":[ 
      { 
         "key":"firebase_event_origin",
         "value":{ 
            "string_value":"auto",
            "int_value":null,
            "float_value":null,
            "double_value":null
         }
      },
      { 
         "key":"system_app",
         "value":{ 
            "string_value":null,
            "int_value":"0",
            "float_value":null,
            "double_value":null
         }
      },
      { 
         "key":"system_app_update",
         "value":{ 
            "string_value":null,
            "int_value":"0",
            "float_value":null,
            "double_value":null
         }
      },
      { 
         "key":"update_with_analytics",
         "value":{ 
            "string_value":null,
            "int_value":"0",
            "float_value":null,
            "double_value":null
         }
      },
      { 
         "key":"previous_first_open_count",
         "value":{ 
            "string_value":null,
            "int_value":"0",
            "float_value":null,
            "double_value":null
         }
      },
      { 
         "key":"firebase_conversion",
         "value":{ 
            "string_value":null,
            "int_value":"1",
            "float_value":null,
            "double_value":null
         }
      }
   ],
   "event_previous_timestamp":null,
   "event_value_in_usd":null,
   "event_bundle_sequence_id":"1",
   "event_server_timestamp_offset":"570847",
   "user_id":null,
   "user_pseudo_id":"d0fb616aca63d545e19d661cf8982517",
   "user_properties":[ 
      { 
         "key":"first_open_time",
         "value":{ 
            "string_value":null,
            "int_value":"1573498800000",
            "float_value":null,
            "double_value":null,
            "set_timestamp_micros":"1573496771938000"
         }
      }
   ],
   "user_first_touch_timestamp":"1573496771938000",
   "user_ltv":null,
   "device":{ 
      "category":"mobile",
      "mobile_brand_name":"Google",
      "mobile_model_name":"Nexus 5X",
      "mobile_marketing_name":null,
      "mobile_os_hardware_model":"Nexus 5X",
      "operating_system":"ANDROID",
      "operating_system_version":"6.0.1",
      "vendor_id":null,
      "advertising_id":"995d360a-e621-4a2d-a747-950de4ce9c6d",
      "language":"ar-om",
      "is_limited_ad_tracking":"No",
      "time_zone_offset_seconds":"14400",
      "browser":null,
      "browser_version":null,
      "web_info":null
   },
   "geo":{ 
      "continent":"(not set)",
      "country":"",
      "region":"",
      "city":"",
      "sub_continent":"(not set)",
      "metro":"(not set)"
   },
   "app_info":{ 
      "id":"com.myapp",
      "version":"1.13.2",
      "install_store":null,
      "firebase_app_id":"1:hidden:android:hidden",
      "install_source":"com.android.vending"
   },
   "traffic_source":{ 
      "name":"(direct)",
      "medium":"(none)",
      "source":"(direct)"
   },
   "stream_id":"1434974637",
   "platform":"ANDROID",
   "event_dimensions":null
}
```